Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor when using smart pointer with std::map()
I am trying to implace a class object into a std::map, and error occurs. Here is the code:
classes.hpp
#ifndef CLASSMETHODNOTCALLED_CLASSES_HPP
#define CLASSMETHODNOTCALLED_CLASSES_HPP

#include "iostream"
#include "memory"

// tow classes with one pointing to the other

class Ca
{
    int m_va = 5;
public:
    Ca();
    int getVa();
};


class Cb
{
    std::unique_ptr<Ca> m_x; // a smart ptr pointing to class Ca
    int m_vb;
public:
    explicit Cb(int n);
    ~Cb();
    int getCa();
};
#endif //CLASSMETHODNOTCALLED_CLASSES_HPP

classes.cpp
#include "../include/classes.hpp"
#include "memory"

// Ca
Ca::Ca()
{

}

int Ca::getVa()
{
    return m_va;
};

// Cb
Cb::Cb(int n)
{
    m_x = std::make_unique<Ca>();
    m_vb = n;
}

Cb::~Cb()
{
}

int Cb::getCa()
{
    return m_x->getVa() + m_vb; // returns 5 + 1 = 6 if works properly
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "include/classes.hpp"
#include "map"

int main()
{
    Cb cb(1);  // instanciate Cb

    std::map<int, Cb> m;
    m.emplace(1, cb); // the line where it complains: Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor
    int i = m.at(1).getCa(); // should return 6 if working properly

//    int i = cb.getCa(); // code without using std::map() works

    std::cout << "va = " << i << std::endl;
}

I think it is caused by the smart pointer whose constructor is explicitly deleted. My question is, how to insert cb into a std::map() in this case? Thank you!
UPDATE:
Now I am trying to get a Cb object from the map, and here is what I did
int main()
{
    Cb cb(1);  // instanciate Cb

    std::map<int, Cb> m;
    m.emplace(1, std::move(cb));

    Cb ccb = m.at(1); // error occurs here complaining Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor
    int i = m.at(1).getCa();

//    int i = cb.getCa();

    std::cout << "va = " << i << std::endl;
}

Any idea?

m.emplace(1, std::move(cb)). But as it says, it will move the contents into the map. cb.m_x will be empty afterwards. The whole point of unique_ptr is to be unique, i.e. not copyable so that two instances refer to the same managed object.

A unique_ptr, or a class with such a member, cannot be copied, it has to be explicitly moved. If it is copied, it is no longer unique!

Also, why is m_x a unique_ptr<Ca> instead of just a Ca? I don't see any reason for that.

And your class violates the rule-of-0/3/5. If your destructor will be defined as empty, then it ought to not be declared at all to follow the rule-of-zero.

c++ std::unique_ptr won't compile in map and C++: insert element into std::map where MyStruct can only be aggregate initialized and contains const unique pointers

#include "iostream" etc. is also wrong. Standard library headers are only guaranteed to work correctly if included with </>.

emplace takes parameters and forwards them to the contructor of the element of the map. If you pass it a Cb it will copy it, if you pass it a rvalue ref it will move it and if you pass it a 1 it will use that to construct the Cb.
Hence, you can

add a move constructor to Cb (Cb(Cb&&)=default; or rather remove your destructor then the compiler can generate both) and do
m.emplace(1,std::move(cb));


or construct the Cb in place
m.emplace(1,1);



But you cannot ask emplace to copy a Cb because Cb has no copy constructor.

Unfortunately, because OP unnecassarily declares a destructor, this will not work automatically with their code for lack of implicit move operations.

@user17732522 yes, they would need to add them, thats why I wrote "add a move constructor" it then works https://godbolt.org/z/sj44Krxvr.

Oh, sorry. Must have skipped that part when reading.

Cb (Cb(Cb&&) = default; does not seem to work?

@NickXTsui yes it does. Why not?

@NickXTsui you have a Cb too many. the sentence reads "Add a move constructor to Cb open bracket  this is how it looks: Cb(Cb&&)= default; close bracket"

@463035818_is_not_an_ai there is a red wiggle underneath default which says "Only special member functions may be defaulted"

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Ok now it works. Thank you so much!

@463035818_is_not_an_ai`Is there anyway you could look at the update section in the original post? I am trying to extract the object from the map, and compilor complains about it. Not sure how to handle this. Thank you so much!!

@NickXTsui please do not alter the question to ask something else after you received answers. You can open a new question (and you should remove the update here)

std::unique_ptr can be moved but not copied.
First, create a move constructor / operator.
class Cb
{
    std::unique_ptr<Ca> m_x; // a smart ptr pointing to class Ca
    int m_vb;
public:
    explicit Cb(int n);
    Cb(Cb&& other) = default;
    Cb& operator=(Cb&& other) = default;
    ~Cb();
    int getCa();
};

And now you can move your Cb:
m.emplace(1, std::move(cb));

Note that m_x of the Cb instance you moved from will become null.
To get an element, you should use a reference:
Cb& elem = map[i];


Defining the move operations manually is the wrong approach. Following the rule-of-zero would be much more appropriate. Even when defining them yourself, they should be defaulted.

the moved from instance will not become "invalid". It will have a m_x that doesnt own a Ca anymore, but otherwise its a totally fine Cb

this part of the code seem to have have problem: Cb& operator=(Cb&& other) {}
m_vb = other.m_vb;
m_x = std::move(other.m_x);
return this;

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I said nothing about Cb being invalid. Only m_x. Invalid is maybe a loose term though.

m_x is not invalid. Its just a unique_ptr that doesnt own an object.

So it is invalid; you can't access its pointed object anymore as it doesn't point to one.
